# Mapping Oracle UDT using c# without stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, mapping, oracle-type

I am required to map an Oracle Object type in my c# application. There are tons of examples online, both here and other sites/blogs, but all of them include using a stored procedure, which I shouldn't do.

I have been searching for the past two days and the closest I got was an article on *docs.oracle.com*, but it is without an example.

Can anyone, please, give an example of how this could be achieved?

I am using `Oracle.DataAccess` class for communication with my database and a simple UDT given below:

```
create or replace 
TYPE "MYNUMBER_TYPE" AS OBJECT (
  MyNumber NUMBER(13)
)
INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to execute PL/SQL you can do something like the following. This is mighty enough to tear the world domination itself. Almost.

Note, this is not tested, as I do not have a Oracle DB here. However I am using this approach in one of my current projects.

```
cmd = New OracleCommand("declare " +
          "    lSomeVarchar2 varchar2(255); " +
          "    lSomeNumber number; " +
          "    lSomeLong long; " +
          "begin " +
          "  loop " +
          "  --do something fancy here  " +
          "  end loop; " +
          "  --you can pass variables from outside: " +
          " :parameterNumber:= lSomeNumber ; " +
          " :parameterVarChar := lSomeLong; " +
          "end;", conn);
          //make these of direction output and you can get values back
cmd.Parameters.Add("parameterNumber", OracleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("parameterVarChar", OracleDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//now you can get the values using something like
int cNumber = (int)cmd.Parameters("parameterNumber").Value;
String myString = (String) cmd.Parameters("parameterNumber").Value;
```

**EDIT 3 aka answer to you comment:**

For usage of the **IOracleCustomType-Interface**:
Again, I couldn't test it as I still don't have access to an Oracle database. However, let's do some magic.

**Step 1:** Create a custom type in your C# code which inherits from IOracleCustomType:

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("C##USER.MYNUMBER_TYPE")]
public class MyCustomClass : IOracleCustomType
```

Then for each class member you have to specify the Oracle pendant. In the following the name "MyNumber" comes from the custom type specification in your question.

```
[OracleObjectMappingAttribute("MyNumber")]
public virtual int cNumber{get; set;}
```

Furthermore you have to override the methods **FromCustomObject** and **ToCustomObject**:

```
//this one is used to map the C# class-object to Oracle UDT
public virtual void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr object){
    OracleUdt.SetValue(conn, object, "MyNumber", this.cNumber);
}

//and this one is used to convert Oracle UDT to C# class
public virtual void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr object){
    this.cNumber = ((int)(OracleUdt.GetValue(conn, object, "MyNumber")));
}
```

**Step 2:** Create the custom type in Database which you already did. So I will not repeat it here.

**Step 3:** Now we are set up. Let's try it:

```
//first create your SQL-Statement
String statement = "SELECT MY_CUSTOM_TYPE_COLUMN FROM MY_SUPER_TABLE";

//then set up the database connection
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("connect string");
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(statement, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//execute the thing
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//get the results
while(reader.Read()){
    MyCustomClass customObject = new MyCustomClass();
    //get the Object, here the magic happens
    customObject = (MyCustomClass)reader.GetValue(0);

    //do something with your object

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I meant was how to implement mapping via custom types in c#. The articles that I read mention `IOracleCustomType` and other interfaces... I didn't quite get it, but maybe you know what's up about that...

Comment: `customObject = (MyCustomClass)reader.GetValue(0)` throws >>>Custom type mapping for 'dataSource='DB' schemaName='C##USER' typeName='MYNUMBER_TYPE'' is not specified or is invalid<<< Do you know why would that be?

Comment: ah, good point, you have to add the custom type mapping `[OracleCustomTypeMapping("C##USER.MYNUMBER_TYPE")]` before your class definition. edited my post above

Comment: Still the same error :) I have posted my complete code in a different question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172178/c-sharp-select-query-to-oracle-database-throws-custom-type-mapping-for-is-n). If you are interested, you can check it out there...